# React-Native on windows 8.1. throwing react-native command not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having issues setting up React-Native on windows 8.1. I have installed react native with the npm install -g react-native-cli yet when I execute react-native init Myproject I get react-native: command not found. I'm using an elevated Powershell so this is rather frustrating. Need your help

Comment: This is because it is not the the Path. Check your path to ensure you have %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\npm or NPM_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the global npm directory to your path, which the Windows installer for current NodeJS Long Term Support release (6.10.x) should have done automatically. I'd recommend uninstalling nodejs, and then reinstalling latest LTS release. That should add the path for you automatically, I just verified as such in a Windows 7 virtual machine.

If that didn't add the path for some reason, you can do it manually from the System control panel.